# How Can I Configure Keepalived to Not Change the Routed Ip?

Tags: networking, server, backup, routing

I am using Keepalived for IP Failover of two IP addresses.

Server 1  : 10.0.0.1 , Master

Server 2  : 10.0.0.2 , Backup

VirtualIp : 10.0.0.3

The virtual IP is set by me on Keepalived configuration file and all connections come to Virtual IP address. If Master is available, all connections are routed to Master. Whenever Master is gone, all connections are routed to Backup. When Master is reachable again, the Keepalived changes the route and routes all connections to Master again. I want to prevent Keepalived to make this. So, if Master is gone and becomes available, Keepalived musn't route the connections to Master, it must continue to route to Backup server. Whenever the backup is gone, it can route to Master again and continues like this. You can imagine this like a toggle operation. If it is possible, how can I do that? I can summarized the problem like this:

```
if Master is available: route connections to Master
if Master is gone: route connections to Backup
if Master was gone and became available: continue to route connections to Backup
if Backup is gone: route connections to Master
if Backup was gone and became available: continue to route connections to Master
```

To simplify the problem, you can imagine as there must be 2 servers as Master-Master without priorities.

Comment: I am not an expert on keepalived, but I see a similar question and some answers here: https://serverfault.com/questions/396839/prevent-master-to-fall-back-to-master-after-failure .. as I read it, setting both servers as BACKUP, maybe with different priority to control which one kicks in, if not the one with lowest ip-address.

Comment: @Soren A thank you. I tried but did not work as I want